# 'dns.rdtypes.*' and 'dns.rdtypes.ANY.*' hook not found when using pyinstaller + dnspython

Tags: python, python-3.x, dns, pyinstaller, dnspython

I am using Python 3.4, PyInstaller (3.0) and dnspython3 (1.12.0).
My script runs fine

```
from dns import resolver,reversename

try:
    host_IP = resolver.query('www.google.ca', 'A')
    print(host_IP[0])
except:
    print('Not found !!')

try:    
    addr = reversename.from_address('8.8.8.8')
    host_name = resolver.query(addr,"PTR")[0].to_text()
    print(host_name)
except:
    print('Not found !!')
```

It returns

```
74.125.225.31
google-public-dns-a.google.com.
```

When I compiled the script, I got the warning

```
... 
5350 INFO: Processing hook   hook-dns.rdata.py   
5366 WARNING: Hidden import 'dns.rdtypes.*' not found (probably old hook)
5366 WARNING: Hidden import 'dns.rdtypes.ANY.*' not found (probably old hook)
...
```

Running the .exe file, it returns

```
\# 4 4a7de117
\# 32 13676f6f676c652d7075626c69632d64 6e732d6106676f6f676c6503636f6d00
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have tried to include these in my script but it does not help either:

```
from dns.rdtypes import *
from dns.rdtypes.ANY import *
```

I am a rookie! Thank you.

Comment: Anyone experiences the same issue? I test with the new PyInstaller 3.1.1 but the results are the same. Please help.